# htaccess rewriting specific folder/path to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to setup a redirect for a site.

I want rewrite file requests from a folder to a subdomain url.

At the moment, I have this in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^g.example.com
RewriteRule ^(uploads/(.*)+ uploads/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

The idea is that when a visitor requests:

```
http://g.example.com/uploads/somefile.png
```

they are served:

```
http://example.com/uploads/somefile.png
```

So it's working as expected. However the problem is that:

```
http://b.example.com/uploads/somefile.png
```

also works.

I only want `http://g.example.com/` to be rewritten. `http://b.example.com/` should 404.

Comment: Let me see if I understood, you want so when a user access `g.example.com` using `GET` it gets served internally with the same file from `example.com`? Does `g` share the same `DocumentRoot` as `example.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^g.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*)\.(JPG|GIF|PNG) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^g.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^GET [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

The first rule will make sure that any URL ending with JPG, GIF, PNG that does not come from `g.example.com` send a 404 not found request to the user.

The second rule makes sure that g.example.com are only accessed using `GET` requests.

Comment: It works, but you can still access via example.com and anything.example.com. I want to 404 other requests

Comment: @user3143218 so if users access using `anything.example.com` or `example.com` it should give them a 404? For images only.

Comment: @user3143218 I've update the rule in a different way, since `g.example.com` is on the same `DocumentRoot` of `example.com` it should be already showing the same content. So what I did is first rule will give a 404 for anything that ends with those extension and are not on the g.example.com. Second rule will only accept requests on g if they are GET.